# Setting the resolution of the slave used by Network Suite of TestComplete wanted

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, testcomplete8

We are using a Network Suite inside of TestComplete 9 to do distributed testing. We have already setup a project that executes on 2 remote computers, our slaves.

Sometimes the resolution on the slave computers is too little though. Seems as if the Remote Desktop Connection is established with a 800*600 resolution only.

Is there a possibility to specify the resolution that will be used in TestComplete? In the the "Display" tab of the Remote Desktop Connection this is possible, this lets me hope this is also possible in TestComplete.

[image]

Comment: It should use the master PC's resolution on all slaves, according to this help topic: http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/27635/

If it does not, makes sense to contact Support and report the problem with any details available: http://support.smartbear.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for vendor support.